# ignite.bat failing to start on windows10 with java 1.8

Tags: java-8, ignite

I downloaded ignited latest binary release 2.13.0. After executing bin/ignite.bat, it gives below error:

```
D:\Programs\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\bin>ignite.bat
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .

D:\Programs\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\bin>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd (build 1.8.0_272-Huawei_JDK_V100R001C00SPC270B002-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJcL.png)

Comment: Can you execute `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and check which java version is used there?

Comment: `D:\Programs\apache-ignite-2.13.0-bin\bin>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd (build 1.8.0_272-Huawei_JDK_V100R001C00SPC270B002-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)`

Comment: can you try openlogic-openjdk-8u292-b10-windows-x64 (JAVA_HOME => D:\Program Files\openlogic-openjdk-8u292-b10-windows-x64\jre)?